# show code modification overview in ecplise IDE

Tags: eclipse

i am using an eclipse based IDE and have a library with some files that i need to make additions/changes to. what is the best way to quickly see the all the modifications of all files in a list/tab in eclipse IDE?

i know there is the useful "@TODO" tag that shows all tasks in a nice view/tab. as im using this quite heavily, i would like to have a special view/tab that just shows the modifications and separates them from the todos.

EDIT:

thx for the suggestions and the local history tipp.

sorry for not making myself clearer. ive added a screenshot.

when i add "TODO" the tasks show up in the tab marked in red - i dont mind setting manually something (like a bookmark) as im not going to make a lot of changes, but ideally they show up like the tasks or another simple overview.

[image: custom list/tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!

by clicking "window" - "Show view" - "other" one needs to select the "bookmarks". the bookmarks then show up as a tab next to tasks.

by clicking the right small arrow the bookmark view menu pops up (similiar to the screenshot above with the task menu). the bookmark view can then be configured/filtered by clicking the "Configure contents..." menu link.

Answer (score 0):

It's could depend of your version control system. 
For each, eclipse purpose an associated plugin with a specific view.

Instead that, you could use the History view (Team/ Show local History after a right clic on a file).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse keeps a history of your changes for a limited number of days (configured in 'Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History'). You can right click on a file and choose 'Compare With > Local History' to see the changes between revisions.

To track all your changes you need to use one of the source control systems (such as SVN, GIT, ...). Eclipse has plugins to support these systems. Once you have installed one of these you can use the 'Team' menu to commit changes and look at the history.